# SQL multiple if's not running on DbUp

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dbup

The following is my code

```
IF NOT EXISTS  (SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects o INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON o.object_id = c.object_id
    WHERE
        o.name = 'portfolioAttributeCodes'
        AND c.name = 'isDisplayed'
)
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE
        [cosmos].[portfolioAttributeCodes]
        ADD
        [isDisplayed] bit DEFAULT 1;
END
IF EXISTS  (SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects o INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON o.object_id = c.object_id
    WHERE
        o.name = 'portfolioAttributeCodes'
        AND c.name = 'isDisplayed')

BEGIN
    UPDATE [cosmos].[portfolioAttributeCodes] SET [isDisplayed] = 1;        
END
```

Now what is happening is it will not create a column (skips the first Id statement and gets into the second one and fails with `Invalid column name 'isDisplayed'`

Can some one help?

Comment: Aside from the compilation error, your code just makes no sense. If we assume the column does, in fact, exist when you run it - it will reset every row in the table to the value of 1. Is that **really** your goal? If the column does not exist, you add it with a default (where every row will automatically have that value populated) and then you update it **again** with the same value. I will guess your logic is over-complicated and that you just need to add the column *with default) if it does not exist and then move on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the table doesn't have the column `isDisplayed` already the entire batch will fail, as the parser will generate an Invalid column name error. This occurs before any of the SQL is run, so it's not that the second `IF` is being entered, *none* of the SQL is run at all. It's effectively a compilation error (like when you try to build you C# application and you have a reference to an object you haven't defined).

You cannot reference a *new* column in the same scope it was created. You would need to use 2 batches or put the reference to the column in a separate scope, so that its validation is deferred.

A deferred validation would seem fine here:

```sql
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM sys.objects o
                    INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON o.object_id = c.object_id
               WHERE o.name = 'portfolioAttributeCodes'
                 AND c.name = 'isDisplayed')
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE [cosmos].[portfolioAttributeCodes]
    ADD [isDisplayed] bit CONSTRAINT DF_isDisplayed DEFAULT 1 WITH VALUES;
END;
ELSE
BEGIN
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql N'UPDATE [cosmos].[portfolioAttributeCodes] SET [isDisplayed] = 1;';
END;
```

I also switch to an `ELSE` as there is little point updating the column after you've created it; just create the column with the values in the first place. *I name the `DEFAULT CONSTRAINT` as well as that's just good habit.*